# How to set UITabBarController when setting initial view controller in app delegate

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I need to programatically set initial view controller (based on user login status).
This is my initial code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let mainRootController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainViewController") as UIViewController
if self.window != nil {

                let navigationController:UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as UINavigationController
                navigationController.viewControllers = [mainRootController]

                self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
}
return true
```

This loads 'MainViewController' fine. But I am missing `UITabBarController` also and I don't know how to set it up programatically here.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    let tabBar = UITabBarController()
    tabBar.viewControllers = [navigationController]
    self.window!.rootViewController
```